# Disable runtime Occlusion Mesh in Vuforia for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

As the title says - I have a model target and most the time I want the Runtime Occlusion Mesh enabled. However I am using a few of the VFX from the VFX Unity library and they do not work with the occlusion mesh. I don't see an option to get or access the mesh at runtime via script (checked in the Model Target Behavior script and Default Observer Event Handler). It doesn't even create a game object at runtime so I'm not sure how to control this feature.

Anyone have any ideas how to turn on and off the occlusion mesh at runtime?

Searching all associated scripts for functions. Found nothing. No game objects are created that I can find at runtime to change.

Comment: From my understanding of [this documentation](https://library.vuforia.com/model-targets/introduction-model-targets-unity) under "Add Runtime Mesh", you can use "Runtime Mesh Rendering Behaviour" component for your purpose to decide to ignore "VuMeshObservationInfo" when u don't want to use occlusion mesh.
May be C++ API usage example might help https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/rendering-in-native/mesh-observer#render-mesh-at-runtime